# AS3 class must inherit from both DisplayObject and another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, inheritance, interface

I have several classes which inherit from display objects (movie clips in my library, each with its own linkage).
All these classes also have similar attributes - certain data that I receive from XML.
I was wondering if it was possible to create a master class which will contain all the properties I want, and also from the display object. Interfaces aren't doing the job, because if I change something on the interface, I still have to go and manually update all the classes implementing it.

Comment: Your base class should inherit from movieClip. The library items linkage classes will inherit from your base class. You put all the code you want in the base class

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of MovieClip that contains your XML attributes, and use this class as superclass of all display assets that share these data.

Comment: This is wrong. He needs at the minimum  to subclass MovieClip since it is being linked from the libray.

Comment: You're right, DisplayObject wouldn't work here. But can't you link Sprite objects as well?

Comment: MovieClips inherit from sprite. MovieClip->Sprite->DisplayObjectContainer->InteractiveObject->DisplayObject->EventDispatcher->Object So if an object needs MovieClip/frame support extending or as you say linking to a Sprite would not have the MovieClip methods needed for the timeline support that the library relies on.

Comment: The only time you would/should ever extend the movieClip class is if you need frame/timeline support.

Comment: Fix your answer so I can +1 you :)

Comment: He might have to have that class of his declared dynamic, as he's using XML to transfer some attributes to class instances.

Comment: @Vesper Extending MovieClip should do that for you. Since MC is a dynamic class extending it should give you a dynamic class also. However I never experimented with that

Comment: @The_asMan Agreed, but in case OP does not explicitly want a MovieClip as common parent (say, he'll be satisfied with Sprite), dynamic declaration will do good for him.

Comment: @Vesper He has no choice but to have MovieClip in the inheritance chain as this class will be linked to MovieClips in the library. For example if the MovieClip in the library has class XYZ set as the base class for it, then by default class XYZ must either extend MovieClip or extend from a class that is inheriting MovieClip.

Comment: Actually, library movieclips can be declared with Sprite as a Base class and they will be exported as Sprites (they won't have MovieClip in the inheritance chain)... thing is only the first frame will ever be visible (which can be a bit confusing). I use this a lot for inheritable assets since I don't really want dynamic classes and I don't use the timeline much...

Answer (score -1):

In ActionScript 3 you can only inherit from single class, you have to use interfaces to achieve it.

Also You can have master class (extending DisplayObject e.g. Sprite) that will always implement the interface (event with empty methods) and any changes to interface will require update to the master class.

Anyway when you will change something there is ALWAYS possibility that change will affect other classes.

Comment: why it was -1? DisplayObject is the right answer MovieClip is DisplayObject! and I gave concrete example of DisplayObject to extend (Sprite) - so why down voted?

Comment: I didn't -1 you but you are wrong. If you have a MovieClip and it's base class inherits from Sprite you will get a compile error along the lines of undefined method addFrameScript and I am sure a few more on top of it. You cn not have a MovieClip extend from a base class that does not offer MovieClip in the inheritance chain.